# facing this error " Uncaught ReferenceError: slideIndex is not defined " in slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, slick.js

I used  slick.js for slider function.

I code code as bellow, but i am facing this error " `Uncaught ReferenceError: slideIndex is not defined` ".

```
<div class=" add-remove ">
   <h3>1</h3>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button js-add-slide">Add Slide</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button js-remove-slide">Remove Slide</a>
</div>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.add-remove').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3
    });
    $('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
      slideIndex++;
      $('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideIndex + '</h3></div>');
    });

    $('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
      $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);
      if (slideIndex !== 0){
        slideIndex--;
      }
    });

    });

</script>
```

help me if anyone have idea to resolve this error.
Thankyou.

Comment: Add `var slideIndex = 0;` at the beginning of `ready()`.

Comment: @Tushar its worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideIndex` is a variable. It is not defined.

Declare `slideIndex` inside `$(document).ready(function() {`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slideIndex = 0; // Add this piece of code
  $('.add-remove').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
  $('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
    slideIndex++;
    $('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd', '<div><h3>' + slideIndex + '</h3></div>');
  });

  $('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
    $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove', slideIndex - 1);
    if (slideIndex !== 0) {
      slideIndex--;
    }
  });

});
```